# overriding an activities onAnimationEnd for the end and start transition

Tags: android, animation, transition

I am trying to override the onAnimationEnd and onAnimationStart for the animations that are used on on starting and finishing the animation. It is just that I cannot figure out how to access them. Where can I access these animations and override these methods?

Below shows my attempt. I feel I am close.... but not quite there.

```
final Animation slideIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_in);
           final Animation slideOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_out);
           overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,  R.anim.slide_out);


           slideIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                camera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;

                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                parameters.setPreviewSize(360, 480);

                camera.setParameters(parameters);

                LogUtils.log("onAnimationEnd");
            }
        });

        slideOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(camera != null && previewing){
                     camera.stopPreview();
                     camera.release();
                     camera = null;

                     previewing = false;

                     LogUtils.log("onAnimationStart");
                  }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: ohk.. so what you catch from this code error or exception :)

Comment: There is no error. I am trying to override the onAnimationEnd and onAnimationStart for the animations that are used on on starting and finishing the animation. It is just that I cannot figure out how to access them. Where can I access these animations and override these methods?

Comment: clean your project and check import http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html